# Overlay image on radio button selection

Tags: css, image

Below is a code snippet from a page that shows attribute options. The code shown is for an item selected by hidden radio button, and the requirement was for the attribute image to be overlaid with a checkmark when selected.
Whilst I have got the checkmark to show on selection, it is always behind the original image. I have tried using z-index, opacity, and also absolute and relative positioning. What is the way to achieve this? I've run out of ideas.
I have already looked at multiple answers for similar questions, but none have worked for me.

```
<div class="attribImg">
<input type="radio" name="id[11]" value="61" checked="checked" id="attrib-11-61" />
<label class="attribsRadioButton four" for="attrib-11-61"><img src="images/attributes/18mg.png" alt="" width="50" height="50" />
</label>
<br />
</div>
```

Css used is:

```
input[type="radio"] {
visibility:hidden;
}
label {
cursor: pointer;
}

.attribImg {z-index:0;}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label{
background:url(../images/checkmark.png) no-repeat 7px -20px;
}
```

Fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/1jcz1xyn/

Comment: What is the purpose of the `<img>` exactly?

Comment: @OriDrori The <img> is a graphical representation of attribute options.
Trying to sort out a fiddle at the moment

Comment: No amount of z-index tweaking will fix this because your `checkmark.png` is the _background_ image, while the `<img src="18mg.png">` is in the _foreground_. You need a different approach.

Comment: @StephenP And what would you suggest?

Comment: @Steve - you could switch it around and make the _graphical representation of attribute options_ the background, and make the checkmark an img ... possibly use `label:after` content, or use a unicode check-mark character instead of the check image, or make them both <img> and position the check over the original image. (I use a lot of unicode checks, arrows, triangles, etc for things I used to use images for, with :before and :after)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `<img>` being inside the `<label>`. No matter the `z-index` you use  on the label, the child (img), will always be above it's parent background, unless you set the child with `z-index: -1` ([updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OriDrori/mok0of8p/) - click the 2nd):

```
.attribImg {
    position: relative; /** this is the positioning context **/
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
input {
    visibility: hidden;
}

label {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label {    background:url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/mimiGlyphs/16/check_mark.png) no-repeat center center;
}
```

Comment: Whilst i can see it works on the fiddle you set up, the above css still results in the checkmark being behind the image in the <img> tag

Comment: If I add your css to the html generated on the site in question, you can see that the checkmark is still behind the main image. http://jsfiddle.net/1jcz1xyn/1/ Second image is blank to show the checkmark is toggling correctly. Is this due to the order in which the html is generated compared to your example html?

Comment: Yep. Forgot to add the changes to the html, and now I see the problem in your fiddle. Fixing.

Comment: Works great. One other question. Is it feasible to make the original image fade slightly when the checkmark is shown?

Comment: Sure. It's very simple, and a transition would be nice as well - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OriDrori/mok0of8p/4/).

Comment: You've been very helpful, but I can't get the opacity to work on the active image I think I've used an earlier version of your responses. My fiddle of exact code and css is http://jsfiddle.net/pzdbte3x/

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you try to manipulate the icon/image with CSS *background-image* only, instead of having one case with *img* and another with CSS. If you do that, z-index won't fix cause it's a logical error.

If you are going to use images/icons (in some cases that's useful for transitions), its also better to add both with the same technique and change the state with css.

So, you can manipulate with CSS:

```
<div class="form-item">
    <label for="radio-1">
        <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radio-1"> <span>Sample 1</span>
    </label>
</div>

label > input[type="radio"]{
    display: none;
}
    input[type="radio"]:checked + span:after{
        font-family:"FontAwesome";
        content: "\f00c";
        margin-left:10px;
    }
```

And you can add both images in the same form-field, and manipulate them with some CSS (And FontAwesome):

```
<div class="form-item">
    <label for="radio-switch-2">
        <input type="radio" name="radios-2" id="radio-switch-2">
        <div class="radio-switch-state">
            <span class="icon-off"></span>
            <span class="icon-on"></span>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>


    input[type="radio"]{
        display: none;
    }
    .radio-switch-state{
        background-color:#aaa;
        display: inline-block;
        color:#fff;
        transition:all .5s ease;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        position: relative;
        overflow:hidden;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
        .radio-switch-state .icon-on,
        .radio-switch-state .icon-off{
            display: inline-block;
            position: absolute;
            width:100%;
            top:0;
        }
        // If you are using font
        .radio-switch-state .icon-on:after,
        .radio-switch-state .icon-off:after{
            font-family:"FontAwesome";
            width:100%;
            display: block;
            line-height:50px;
            position: absolute;
            transition:all .5s ease;
        }
            .radio-switch-state .icon-on:after{
                content: "\f00c";
                margin-left:100;
                left:100%;
            }
            .radio-switch-state .icon-off:after{
                content: "\f056";
                left:0;
            }
                .radio-switch-state:hover{
                    background-color:#FFA374;
                    cursor:pointer;
                }
                input[type="radio"]:checked + .radio-switch-state{
                    background-color:#FA8144;
                }
            input[type="radio"]:checked + .radio-switch-state .icon-on:after{
                content: "\f00c";
                margin-left:100;
                left:0;
            }
            input[type="radio"]:checked + .radio-switch-state .icon-off:after{
                content: "\f056";
                left:-100%;
            }
```

[I made a Pen with both samples.](http://codepen.io/teefars/pen/qOZpZL?editors=110)

Also, when using icons try to use an icon font library, like FontAwesome or Glyphicon.

---

Edit - Added a sample with images

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this variant will help you? It's without any changes to HTML. I've used ::after instead and here's the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mvchalov/1jcz1xyn/2/

```
input[type="radio"]:checked+label::after{
background:url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/mimiGlyphs/16/check_mark.png) no-repeat center center;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    position: absolute;
    content:'';
    margin:0 0 0 -50px;
}
```

Comment: A very neat idea, although when testing I did find one issue. If there is a price supplement shown, the checkmark displays adjacent to the text rather than over the image.
See the fiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/ckbc0oLb/

Comment: Thanks! It's not such a big issue, check the update: http://jsfiddle.net/mvchalov/ckbc0oLb/1/

Comment: Almost perfect. Only problem is that the checkmark is also being affected by opacity. It needs to be opacity only on the main image so that the checkmark stands out clearly.

Comment: Which browser shows the checkmark with opacity < 1? I've checked it in the most common browsers, and it has opacity: 1 everywhere.